# ng-upload-file and django rest framework post and update data with filefield

Tags: angularjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

1. using django rest framework as backend and angularjs as frontend
2. backend

   ```
   class ReleaseBugs(models.Model):
       bug_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
       bug_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='release_bugs/')

   class ReleaseBugsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = ReleaseBugs
           fields = '__all__'
   ```
3. frontend

   ```
   Upload.upload({
           method: 'PUT',
           url: api_url + '/' + data.id + '/' ,
           data: data
       }).then();

   Upload.upload({
           method: 'POST',
           url: api_url + '/' + data.id + '/' ,
           data: data
       }).then();
   ```
4. the question
   when the first upload an image, its done, the backend convert bug_image to url, than when i want to revise the data, eg, the bug_name, and post again, it was forbidden.
   I have a solution for this, when repost the data, using ng-upload-file to convert the url to blob

   ```
   Upload.urlToBlob($scope.release_bug.bug_image).then(function(blob) {
                   $scope.release_bug.bug_image = blob;
                   // do post
               });
   ```

   however, this way just upload the same image with different filename. It's a waste of time and space, i think.

I'm new to this, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: came up a solution, just do update at the viewset update, not use the serilizer

Answer (score 0):

came up a solution, just do update at the viewset update, not use the serilizer

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request_bug_image = request.data['bug_image']
    release_bug = ReleaseBugs.objects.get(pk=int(kwargs['pk']))
    for key, value in request.data.iteritems():
        if key == 'bug_image' and isinstance(request_bug_image, basestring):
            continue
        setattr(release_bug, key, value)
    release_bug.save()
    release_bug_serializer = ReleaseBugsSerializer(release_bug)
return Response(release_bug_serializer.data)
```